# Variables declared inside and outside brackets of @interface

Tags: objective-c, scope, global-variables, instance-variables, variable-declaration

Why do you have to declare variables inside the `@interface` brackets like this?

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController {
     NSString *myString;
     IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
}
```

Why not just do it here?

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController {
     IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
}

NSString *myString;
```

Comment: The short answer is "because that's what the language dictates".

Comment: No, I mean to say what is the difference? Does it matter whether you put it in the brackets?

Comment: @user2002708 You do, see my answer.

Comment: You can declare it like this:
`@interface myClass : UIViewController {
     IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSString *myString;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because if you don't, then the variable will be a file-scope variable (with static storage duration) and it won't be an **instance variable** of your class.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first form is correct Objective-C syntax for declaring instance variables. The second form doesn't define an instance variable, it defines a global. If you wish to define a global, define it before the `@interface` block so it's doesn't appear to be part of the class definition.

Outside the curly braces is the place for method and property declarations.

But better yet, private ivars should be declared in the .m file, not the .h file.

```
@implementation myClass {
    // private ivars here
}
```

I don't think this applies to `IBOutlet` though. I think they need to be in the .h file. But I don't use IB so I don't know for sure.

Comment: No, the second form is perfectly valid too. It will be a file-scope variable in the second case, not an instance variable, though.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about that (since I never do that).

Answer (score 0):

The way we are supposed to do that is like bellow:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

Just follow the conventions and do not complicate your developer's life ;)

Comment: The question was why to use one format over the other. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok, then the answer you probably figured out is that you should put all you variables inside the square brackets if you want them to be private, and outside - if you want to be accessible from other classes, but it is highly recommended to make properties in such cases. Hope that helps

Comment: Putting them outside of the curly braces makes them global variables, not public instance variables. You can have public instance variables by putting them inside the curly braces and adding the `public:` keyword.